# pip3 and requests module AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or global variable named 'Cryptography_HAS_CMS'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-requests

There is a problem with pip3 & python3 requests module with OpenSSL

```
→ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 54, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 156, in <module>
    Binding.init_static_locks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 137, in init_static_locks
    cls._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-

packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 124, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    cls.lib = build_conditional_library(lib, CONDITIONAL_NAMES)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 84, in build_conditional_library
    if not getattr(lib, condition):
AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or global variable named 'Cryptography_HAS_CMS'



→ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

- On Python3 Shell:

---

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 156, in <module>
    Binding.init_static_locks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 137, in init_static_locks
    cls._ensure_ffi_initialized()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 124, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
    cls.lib = build_conditional_library(lib, CONDITIONAL_NAMES)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 84, in build_conditional_library
    if not getattr(lib, condition):
AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or global variable named 'Cryptography_HAS_CMS'
>>>
```

- I Assume the problem is with `openssl`, Please help me debug it and solve it.

---

```
→ apt-get remove openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cloud-init : Depends: python3-requests (>= 0.8.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: software-properties-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

---

Successfully removed and installed, problem still persist.

```
apt-get remove python3-pip

apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
→ cd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
→ mv OpenSSL OpenSSL-back
→ mv pip pip-back
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-cryptography
apt-get remove python3-pip
apt-get install python3-pip
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: for me already step 1 deleting `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages$ rm -r OpenSSL/` solved the problem